# Strange result when using #each_with_index to change an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to write some code that will loop through an array of strings, clean up the entries, and then add the cleaned up entries to a hash that tracks the frequency with which each word appears. This was my first solution:

```
puts("Give me your text.")
text = gets.chomp

words = text.split
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
words.map! do |word|
  word.tr("\",.", "")
end
words.each do |word|
  frequencies[word] += 1
end
```

It works fine, but looping through the array twice feels very inefficient, so I've been trying to find a way to do it one go and stumbled upon the following:

```
puts("Give me your text.")
text = gets.chomp

words = text.split
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
words.each_with_index do |word, index|
  words[index].tr!("\",.", "")
  frequencies[word] += 1
end
```

Based on my understanding of `each_with_index`, this shouldn't work, but somehow it does, and the hash receives the clean version of each string: https://repl.it/B9Gw. What's going on here? And is there a different way to solve this problem without looping twice?

EDIT: After some reading, I was able to solve the problem using just one loop in the following way:

```
puts("Give me your text.")
text = gets.chomp

words = text.split
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
for i in 0..words.length-1
  words[i].tr!("\",.", "")
  frequencies[words[i]] += 1
end
```

However, this is more of a JS or C++ solution and doesn't seem like idiomatic Ruby. Are there any other options? Also, why does the `each_with_index` approach even work?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `String#tr!` method, which modifies the string destructively instead of returning a new string. The fact that you are looking it up on the hash again (using `words[index]`) doesn't change anything, because the string object is still the same - so the `word` you use to modify the `frequencies` hash is also modified.

> And is there a different way to solve this problem without looping twice?

An obvious way would be to use the same logic that you used, but without the `with_index` (which isn't making any difference here anyway). I would advise using the non-destructive `String#tr` instead of `String#tr!`, to make it more clear which strings have been cleaned and which have not.

```
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
words.each do |word|
  cleaned = word.tr("\",.", "")
  frequencies[cleaned] += 1
end
```

If you want to make clear the `map` phase of the process and still only loop once, you can leverage ruby's lazy enumerators:

```
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
cleaned_words = words.lazy.map { |word| word.tr("\",.", "") }

cleaned_words.each do |cleaned|
  frequencies[cleaned] += 1
end
```

Here, even though we do a `map` and then an `each`, the collection is only traversed once, and ruby doesn't create any intermediary arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. My understanding is that `word` is assigned a certain value before each pass through the loop, so the changes made to the array by `words[index].tr!("\",.", "")` shouldn't affect it. Consider the following example:

    `array = [1, 2, 3]
    array.each_with_index do |element, index|
      array[index] += 1
    puts element
    end`

The values that get printed out here are the original values in the array. Also, your alternate solution isn't equivalent because it leaves the original array unchanged, and I would like it to get updated.